# FileReader over an InputStreamReader

Tags: java

I am going over `java.io` and some aspects are confusing to me:
Is there any perfomance difference between `FileReader` and `InputStreamReader` ?

```
Reader fileReader = new FileReader("input.txt");
Reader fileReader2 = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));
```

Which one is preferable over another one ?

Comment: Questions like this are a sign that the person asking the question has an unhealthy obsession with performance.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference. You can understand this looking into the source code:

```
public class FileReader extends InputStreamReader {
    // ...
    public FileReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(new FileInputStream(fileName));
    }
    // ...
}
```

So this is merely a syntactic sugar. `FileReader` extends `InputStreamReader`, but has no additional changes except constructors.

Also note that `FileReader` uses system default file encoding and there's no way to specify the custom encoding with it. This I'd recommend not to use it at all. In modern Java 1.7+ NIO there are new preferred methods:

`java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Path)`: new UTF-8 `BufferedReader`
`java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Path, Charset)`: new `BufferedReader` with specified `Charset`.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't focus on the performance. I'd focus on the massive *correctness* difference between them: `FileReader` *always* uses the platform-default encoding, which is almost never a good idea.

I believe that's actually slightly more efficient (at least in some cases) than specify a `Charset` in the `InputStreamReader` constructor, even if you pass in the platform-default `Charset`, but I would still do the latter for clarity and correctness.

Of course, these days I'd probably go straight to `Files.newBufferedReader` as a simpler approach that a) let's me specify the `Charset`; b) defaults to UTF-8 which is what I normally want anyway; c) creates a `BufferedReader` which is also what I often want, mostly for the sake of `readLine()`.